# "SceneKit: error, missing buffer [-1/2]" when trying to pass uniforms to a metal shader

Tags: ios, swift, shader, scenekit, metal

I've attached a SCNProgram to a SceneKit's geometry, and I'm trying to pass uniforms to the fragment shader. In my simple code snippet I just pass the output color to the fragment shader as a uniform, which returns it as an output value.

I've already tested the shaders and they work, in the sense that I can succesfully rotate an object in the vertex shader, or draw an object in a different color in the fragment shader, etc... but the problem is when I pass the uniforms. This is my fragment shader:

```
struct Uniforms
{
    float4 color;
};


fragment float4 myFragment(MyVertexOutput in [[ stage_in ]],
                           constant Uniforms& uniforms [[buffer(2)]])
{
    return uniforms.color;
}
```

And this is how I try to pass the uniforms in my SceneKit+Swift code:

```
SCNTransaction.begin()
cube.geometry?.setValue(NSValue(SCNVector4:SCNVector4(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0)), forKey: "uniforms.color")
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

But my object (it's a cube) is not even drawn (it's black), and I get this error:

> 2016-04-01 01:00:34.485 Shaded Cube[30266:12687154] SceneKit: error, missing buffer [-1/0]

**EDIT**
I tried to follow @lock's suggestions, but I'm still getting the same error. This is the full project repository: https://github.com/ramy89/Shaded-Cube.git

Comment: Hi Ramy could I email you about a potential project? Couldn't find your email address on the GitHub page. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shader code looks fine, and the way you're passing the uniform in is close to working.

The name of the shader uniform must match that which is used in `setValue`. In this case your Metal variable name is `uniforms` and the value you use in `setValue` is `uniforms.color`. These don't match, hence the error you see. Suggest changing the swift code to simply use `uniforms` in the `setValue` call.

Next you need to ensure the data passed in as the value to `setValue` is the same in both Metal and Swift. A `SCNVector4` is a struct of four 64bit doubles (CGFloats), whereas Metal's `float4` is a struct of four 32bit floats. The documentation seems to indicate you can pass in a SCNVector as a NSValue but I've never got it to work.

In your swift code I'd create a struct to contain the uniforms you want to pass in. There's not a lot of documentation on the `vector_float4` struct, but it matches the Metal `float4` struct in that it is four 32bit floats.

```
struct Uniforms {
    var color:vector_float4
}
```

Pass this into the `setValue` function as `NSData`.

```
let myColor = vector_float4(0,1,0,1)
var myUniforms = Uniforms(color:myColor)
var myData = NSData(bytes:&myUniforms, length:sizeof(Uniforms))
cube.geometry?.setValue(myData, forKey: "uniforms")
```

I'm not sure you need the `SCNTransaction` calls, I've not needed them in past and they could be costly performance wise.

**update**

After looking at Ramy's code it seems there is an issue with setValue and SCNPrograms when applied to the geometry. I can't tell you why, but setting the custom shader to the material seems to fix this, eg;

```
func makeShaders()
{
    let program = SCNProgram()
    program.vertexFunctionName = "myVertex"
    program.fragmentFunctionName = "myFragment"
    //cube.geometry?.program = program
    cube.geometry?.firstMaterial?.program = program

    var uniforms = Uniforms(color: vector_float4(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0))
    let uniformsData = NSData(bytes: &uniforms, length: sizeof(Uniforms))
    //cube.geometry?.setValue(uniformsData, forKey: "uniforms")
    cube.geometry?.firstMaterial?.setValue(uniformsData, forKey: "uniforms")
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error, I don't know what's wrong with my code. I created a github repository and added the link to my question.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your code @RamyAlZuhouri, see my update above. Looks like a SceneKit bug to me, probably worth filling out a radar.